# Making a Calendar; changing year, when a month is greater than december, or lower than january

Tags: android, date, kotlin, calendar

I'm creating an app in which I want to save some data in different months. I want make that when you press a button, a month is changing and if a month is higher than December, or lower than January, the year is changing I have only changing month, when it comes to change year there is a little problem, that a year changes from 2019 to 2020, but month change to January 2020, and I can't change to February 2020.
Here is a code, if i something is not clear, just ask me

```
        //initialize calendar
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    //set month counter
    var monthInt:Int

    // check if the intent from pressing button, has any extras, if don't set monthInt to 0
    if(!intent.hasExtra("monthInt")) {
        monthInt = 0
    }else{
        monthInt = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("monthInt").toString())
    }

    //get date, set title with date
    var year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    var month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)

    //add to month 1 to make it range from 1 to 12
    month += 1

    // add month counter
    month += monthInt

    //check if month is greater than 12 or lower than 1 than change year
    if(month > 12){
        month = 1
        year += 1
    }else if(month < 1){
        month = 12
        year += -1
    }

    //get buttons views
    var prevButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.prevButton)
    var nextButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextButton)


    //set listeners to change month
    prevButton.setOnClickListener{
        monthInt -= 1
        intent.putExtra("monthInt", (monthInt).toString())
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    nextButton.setOnClickListener{
        monthInt += 1
        intent.putExtra("monthInt", monthInt.toString())
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: You are doing too much hand coding. The `YearMonth` class of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) can do that for you. Or if you insist, the `Calendar` class can, but it’s poorly designed and long outdated, and java.time is so much nicer to work with. If not yet on Android API level 26, use it through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is created every time

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
```

..

```
var year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
var month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

will be called which seem to be the issue